# Proof of probability version of Shannon's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I was working on excercise 10.16 of Folland, which is named Shannon's theorem:

> Let $X_j$ be a sequence of independent random variables on the sample space $\Omega$ that have common distribution $\lambda=\sum_1^rp_j \delta_j$ where $p_j \in (0,1)$. Define random variables $Y_n$ on $\Omega$ to be $Y_n(\omega)=P(\{\omega': X_i(\omega')=X_i(\omega) for\ 1\leq i \leq r\})$. Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}n^{-1}\text{log}Y_n=\sum_1^rp_j\text{log}p_j$ almost surely.

I was able to see that if we define $Z_i$ is actually just a variable that evaluated $p_i$ on the set where $X_i$ takes value of $i$,then $Y_n=\Pi_1^{n}Z_i$. But then what to do to prove the almost sure part? I've got no idea what theorem to be used in this problem(the theorems just introduced are the large number laws and Borel-Cantelli lemma) and also how to deal with the log expressionn.

Any comment or help is appreciated.

Comment: $Y_n$ does not depend on $n$?

Answer (score 2):

If $Y_n$ equals $\prod_1^n Z_i$, check that the $Z_1,Z_2,\ldots,Z_n$ are independent and identically distributed, so that $\log(Z_1),\log(Z_2)\ldots,\log(Z_n)$ are also independent and identically distributed. We then have $n^{-1}\log Y_n=n^{-1}\sum_1^n \log(Z_i)$ is the sample mean of a sequence of i.i.d. random variables. Applying the strong law of large numbers, the almost sure limit of $n^{-1}\sum_1^n \log(Z_i)$ is the expected value of $\log(Z)$. If you've defined the $Z_i$ properly, this expected value should work out to $\sum_1^r p_j\log p_j$.

Comment: Thanks! I should be able to see it...